# How can someone make a user application on blockchain that is not any exchange or trading one, but a normal one like youtube that is feasible?

Tags: blockchain, gas, dapps

Just a curious question.. please let me know your thoughts and knowledge on this.

I'm a beginner in web 3.0, and as far as I know everything is a transaction in blockchain and for each transaction to happen you need to pay a fee. So, If I want to build a normal decentralized application like a youtube clone but decentralized then... how is it even feasible to that?
I know that the data can be stored in technologies like IPFS or other cloud servers etc. while the metadata will be in blockchain.

But let say someone likes a video, and that has to be updated in the smart contract, isn't it a transaction.. which means it has to be paid.. why would someone pay for upvoting a video? Doesn't make any sense?
I know there is some misunderstanding in my knowledge and thinking that is leading to this confusion. Kindly explain it, if possible.